# Transit visa for India-Germany-Amsterdam

Tags: visas, germany, transit-visas, netherlands

I am travelling from India to Netherlands, and have Schengen visa for Netherlands.
I have a flight layover at Frankfurt, Germany.

Do I need a transit visa for changing flights (same terminal)?

Comment: You already have a visa. Germany is in the Schengen area and that's where you will enter it.

Comment: I have a single entry business purpose Schengen VISA, is it alright?

Answer (score 3):

No you don't.

Once you enter Germany, you'll already be inside the Schengen zone. In effect, your flight from Germany to Netherlands is a "domestic" flight, because you don't need separate visa to transit between these two Shengen member states.

The single entry means you can enter once to the Schengen zone; so you'll be fine (as long as you don't exit the Schengen area - which as per your question you are not planning to).